# Get photos from non-photo stream on iPhone to PC

Tags: iphone, ios

Here's what happened. My iPhone had the power button break, so I copied all of my photos off of my iPhone's Camera Roll onto my work iMac. Then they replaced my iPhone with a brand new one, which I then put all of the pictures from my iMac back onto. Now I'm home where I have a PC and I need to get the photos off of my iPhone. Normally I just connect it and move the photos off of my iPhone using Windows Explorer, however that apparently only works with photos in your Camera Roll album, and all of the pictures I transferred back to my phone ended up in a different album which does not show up in Windows Explorer. Is there any way to get these photos off of my iPhone onto my PC?

More info: When I connect to iTunes it can see that I have 3.5GB of photos on the phone, but it gives me no access to them that I can see.

Everything I've Google'd for has given advice for going from Camera Roll only, and I can't seem to move my pictures into the Camera Roll so that doesn't help. Even iCloud will only back-up your Camera Roll. It's like nothing can see the photos I've put on the phone, iTunes can only see the space taken by them.

Until I get these photos off my phone I can't restore my phone to its last back-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research it seems like the only way to do this is by using special software, none of which are free.

My solution was a lengthy workaround of copying my photos off of my iMac, and onto a DVD, then offload them onto my home computer.